# read only some properties using ResourceBundle

Tags: java, properties, resourcebundle

I have a big file with messages specified in locale. For example:

```
book.registration.error.service = ..
book.registration.error.empty.book = ..
book.registration.error.file.format.book = ..

publisher.register.firstpublisher = ..
publisher.register.publisherNameUa = ..
publisher.register.nameRu = ..
publisher.register.NameEn = ..
```

There is a lot of messages. To read them I use

```
java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(messagesLocation, locale)
```

but with whis i will read ALL messages. Is there any way to read only a piace of messages. For example read only messages which start with 'book'?

Comment: Why is that bad? I suppose you keep that bundle for later use?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish what you want is to break up your very large resource bundle into multiple bundles - and put all the "book" ones into a specific bundle.

You could parse the file yourself, but you'd still have to essentially read through the entire file (unless it's sorted), but that seems to defeat the purpose of what you're trying to achieve.

Typically you'd only go down this road if you're having memory or performance problems with a single bundle - if it's memory problems, breaking up bundles might help; if it's performance problems, initializing your bundle on a background thread may help.

And in case it's not obvious - you should always cache the bundle! Re-creating your bundle every time is a waste - if you want to support dynamically changing resources, just invalidate the cache when resources actually change.

Comment: The [documentation for ResourceBundle.Control.getTimeToLive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html#getTimeToLive-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) indicates that cacheing is always performed, unless one explicitly disables it.

Comment: @VGR - Shiny :) - (It's been a while since I really used ResourceBundle - back when caching had to be done manually)